# VBA Excel Use row with most recent date

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a VBA script to find the row with the most recent date value for each unique value of another cell.

For example:

[image]

I would like to have all the data corresponding with unique values of A (City) and only the most recent date.

So it should look a little bit like:

[image]

Like mentioned it should sort all data in all columns, not only A and B.

Does anybody have an idea how this could be done the best way? I was trying to use formulas but I wasn't succesful so far.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I am currently working on a VBA script". Then why have you tagged the question with VB.NET?

Comment: Please do not use unrelated tags. It is very annoying for those interested in a specific tag to read questions that do not concern them. What is VB.NET's role in this question?

Comment: What have you researched / tried, so far? Post your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an array formula. Assuming your data is in columns A:B and you have `NYC` in Cell `D1` then you can do:

```
=MAX(IF(D1=A1:A100, B1:B100, 0))
```

That's an array formula so you'll have to enter it in by holding Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Once you get that list, you can do a VLookup or similar to pull over the rest of the values.